# Running my python loop on a df and print responses in df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
                     Domain     Use
0        graph.facebook.com    4242
1            news.bbc.co.uk   23423
2  news.more.news.bbc.co.uk  234432
3       profile.username.co  235523
4           offers.o2.co.uk  235523
5     subdomain.pyspark.org    2325
6       uds.data.domain.net   23523
7         domain.akamai.net   23532
```

And I have a script which I can run against a single column of the dataframe: This works exactly as I want.

```
In [13]: for row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     cdns = ['akamai', 'maxcdn', 'cloudflare']
    ...:     tld = ['co.uk', 'com', 'org', 'co', 'net']
    ...:     index = df.Domain[df.Domain.str.strip().str.endswith(tuple(tld))].str.split('.').tolist()
    ...:
    ...: for x in index:
    ...:     if (x[len(x)-2]) in cdns:
    ...:         if str(x[len(x)-1]) in tld:
    ...:             print(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...:     elif (x[len(x)-2]) in cdns:
    ...:         if str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
    ...:              print(str(x[len(x)-4])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...:     elif str(x[len(x)-2]).rstrip()+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]).rstrip() in tld:
    ...:         print(str(x[len(x)-3])+'.'+str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
    ...:     elif str(x[len(x)-1]) in tld:
    ...:          print(str(x[len(x)-2])+'.'+ str(x[len(x)-1]))
```

But, I need to add a new column to the dataframe with the result of my script as the contents. So I want to have the columns:
- DOMAIN
- USE
- NEW DOMAIN

Where newdomain = the result of my script.

How might I do that? I've searched high and low but no success

**UPDATE**
I've tried the below - but it adds the series called index to the column. I need the result of my for loop instead:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
                     Domain     Use
0        graph.facebook.com    4242
1            news.bbc.co.uk   23423
2  news.more.news.bbc.co.uk  234432
3       profile.username.co  235523
4           offers.o2.co.uk  235523
5     subdomain.pyspark.org    2325
6       uds.data.domain.net   23523
7         domain.akamai.net   23532

In [15]: df['newdomain']=index

    In [16]: df
    Out[16]: 
                         Domain     Use                        newdomain
    0        graph.facebook.com    4242           [graph, facebook, com]
1            news.bbc.co.uk   23423              [news, bbc, co, uk]
2  news.more.news.bbc.co.uk  234432  [news, more, news, bbc, co, uk]
3       profile.username.co  235523          [profile, username, co]
4           offers.o2.co.uk  235523             [offers, o2, co, uk]
5     subdomain.pyspark.org    2325        [subdomain, pyspark, org]
6       uds.data.domain.net   23523         [uds, data, domain, net]
7         domain.akamai.net   23532            [domain, akamai, net]
```

So the for loop will output : facebook.com, bbc.co.uk, etc.

Comment: `df['New Domain']=series_result` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, by doing that, i get the result ffrom index printed in the df - do you know how I can get the result of my for loop in there?

Comment: I don't know how your result looks like. Just post the relevant code here in which you are facing trouble. Add your final result here.

Comment: Just updated the description :-) thanks again

Comment: So what is the result of the loop?

Comment: The loop output is: facebook.com
bbc.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
username.co
o2.co.uk
pyspark.org
domain.net
net.domain.akamai.net

Comment: it'd the cleaned example of the domains (without sub domains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Domain':[' graph.facebook.com','news.bbc.co.uk ']})
df['new_domain']=df.Domain.str.split('.',1, expand=True)[1] # split on '.' then take second element
```